# Linuxによるクラスタシステムの導入について

Tags: linux

Linux(UBUNTU)で、２台構成のクラスタ運用を検討していますが、（DBはMysql）
ホットスタンバイで、フェールオーバーに対応したいと思っていますが、
以下の実現は可能でしょうか？

１．アプリケーションが、自ノードがマスターなのか、スレーブなのか取得したい。
２．自動フェールオーバーの実現。（アプリケーションはマスター切り替えを認識したい。）
３．ミドルウェア（ClusterPro等）の導入が必須？

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: クラスタ運用対象はmysqlサーバのみでしょうか? 他のソフトウェアも対象でしょうか? 対象を質問に追記すると、回答が得られやすいかと思います。

Comment: クラスタ構成になるのは、他ノードとのソケット通信です。

Comment: 前提となる システムのアーキテクチャを追記してもらうことはできますか？できればえれば Mysqlだけ考慮すれば良いのか、それ以外も考慮する必要があるのかといったことが わかるので 回答が付きやすくなると思います。（たとえば、Web3レイヤーで言語はJava＆クライアントはWebブラウザ、であるとか、サバクラ構成でサーバーはC++、クライアントは別PC上のWindowsアプリとかです）

Comment: @MitsuoTAKEI  想定しているのが「DB=MySQLのクラスタ」であるなら、そちらを主にタイトルや本文を記載してもらった方が目に留まりやすいと思います(「クラスタ」はDB以外にも広く使われる言葉です)。質問は後からでも「編集」できますので、補足事項も含めて見直しをしてみてください。

Comment: つまり、Mysqlは 今回の質問の要旨とは関係ないということでいいですか？第三者が読んでわかり易い文章でないと回答はつきにくいと思います。一度質問文をご自身で読み返してみて、第三者に質問の意図が伝わるかどうか レビューしてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: ご検討ありがとうございます。クラスター化の対象は、Mysqlだけでなく、他のサブシステムとTCPソケットを通して通信（メッセージ交換）するアプリケーションです。メッセージ交換の際に、Mysqlを参照、更新を行うシステムです。

Comment: システムの内容ですが、ロードバランサー2台構成で、TCPソケットを使用し、他のシステムとのメッセージのやり取りをします。
ソケット接続はパフォーマンス向上の為、接続はしたまま、マスターとして動作します。一方のスレーブは、親プロセスのみが常駐し、コネクションは接続しないまま、待機します。障害時はスレーブがマスターに切り替わってコネクションを接続し、サービスを継続します。
したがいまして、アプリケーションで自分がマスターなのかスレーブなのかを意識しなければなりません。また、障害発生時はスレーブからマスターへの切り替えを察知し、コネクションをしなければなりません。

Answer (score 1):

質問に対しては、以下のように考えます。

＃「ホットスタンバイ」は「両ノードでアプリケーションが起動している状態で、一方だけ処理する」冗長方式という前提です。
＃アプリケーションがいわゆる「サーバソケット」で接続を待ちうける前提です。

1. アプリケーションが、自ノードがマスターなのか、スレーブなのか取得したい。
   → 各ノードのアプリケーション間で「ハートビート通信」を行うよう実装することで、互いの状態を交換することが可能と思います。
2. 自動フェールオーバーの実現。
   → 同上です。「ハートビート通信」が失敗したことを契機に、スレーブがマスターに昇格するようにすることで、実現可能と思います。
3. ミドルウェア（ClusterPro等）の導入が必須？
   → 上記の動作を実現しているのが、クラスタソフト(ミドルウェア)です。ですので、アプリケーションで実装するメリットがあるかないかで判断することになると思います。

---

なお、実現したいことを鑑みると、クラスタソフトを導入して、「ウォームスタンバイ」(マスターノードのみでアプリケーションが起動し、フェールオーバーでスタンバイノードでアプリケーションを起動させる)で冗長化するようにしたほうが、実現は楽かと思います。

- アプリケーションはノード間で1つしか起動していないので、マスター/スレーブを意識する必要がない。
- 故障時に問題となりやすい「スプリットブレイン」等は、クラスタソフトが解決してくれる。
- DBサーバはウォームスタンバイの方が、ノード間でデータ不整合が起きない。(両ACTの場合、レプリケーションする方法になるが、不整合が発生する可能性がある)